# Rails 3 Expire complex actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

Let's say I have this in my controller:

```
caches_action :my_action, :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| "my_action##{c.params}" }
```

Where the url is something like:

```
/w/:some_id/:additional_params
```

The caching works just fine, however I can't find how to expire it.

I've tried:

```
expire_action(:controller => '/my_controller', :action => 'my_action')

expire_fragment(/my_action/)

store = ActionController::Base.cache_store
store.delete_matched(/my_action/)
```

But none is expiring my action. Any idea if it's possible to expire a matching action like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments at [Caching docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Caching/Actions) you could add `:expires_in` option:

```
caches_action :my_action, :expires_in => 1.hour,
  :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| "my_action##{c.params}" }
```

Also, as you indicated, your URL-s are in the form of `/w/:some_id/:additional_params` so there is no `my_action` in the url. So you won't match any objects with regexp `/my_action/`.

Probably this would expire cache:

```
expire_fragment(%r{/w/\d+/})
```

Comment: Right, but there is "my_action" in the cache_path. I'll try your suggestion.